# MongoDB: Find function not working in JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

On my localhost/list page, my GET is showing

```
[{"_id":"5756f1aa64fa4d3104f98f89","mcr":"relationship","info":{"test":"test"}}]
```

but I would like to only return

```
[{"info":{"test":"test"}}]
```

My find function works just fine on the mongo command line and it returns what is expected.:

```
db.usercollection.find({},{"_id":0,"mcr":0})
```

However, when called in my JS file, it doesn't filter out the query. I'm using express and monk along with MongoDB. This is my router.get:

```
router.get('/list', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('usercollection');
collection.find({},{"_id":0,"mcr":0},function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs);
});
});
```

No errors are thrown and the status code is 200, what could the problem be? I've tried a ton of variations within the find function, and haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, apparently mongo hadn't updated their docs completely. I needed to use {fields: {_id:0}}.

Final code:

```
router.get('/list', function(req, res) {
    req.db.get('usercollection').find({},{fields: {"_id":0,"mcr":0}},function(e,docs){
        res.json(docs);
        //console.log(docs);
    });
});
```